# Recycler view object not updated on completion of activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I have a fragment consisting of a recycler list view which has a text view and like button which on item click would launch a new activity with the same expanded layout consisting of a like button. On passing an object from the adapter to the activity on click of an item and updating it there in another activity is not updating the recycler list view item when the another activity is finished.

> Note: Working if I refresh but the problem is this causes a serious User experience issue of moving him away from the content he is reading. Say he is reading the 8th item and while refreshing I will move him to the first item again.

Help required in updating the same object or an alternative workaround.Thank you for your time and effort in going through till the end.

Comment: Can you clarify a little bit more what's happening when the activity is finished? The row item itself isn't updating? Are you calling `notifyDataSetchanged()` on the adapter?

Comment: @McAdam331 The row item consists of a post and a like button when I click on the post I am starting a new activity to display the post if the length of post is greater than 250 characters. So while clicking I am using the same layout so once again I get the row with complete text and a like button. If I click the like button here and press the back button (a button on the top bar) or the physical button I would be going to the fragment where the list is loaded but doesn't reflect the updation of like button that I clicked in the detailView activity. Hope  I am clear if not will try to explain

Comment: @McAdam331 I don't want to refresh the complete list which has 100 posts for updating the single item also causing a UX issue of going to the top while the user is reading the 10th post say -> on finishing I would be redirected to the 1st post again.Please let me know if there is a way or a workaround to do the same

Comment: Hmm. In a really short and sweet version you can keep track of which post you click on, and when you come back do notifyItemChanged: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemChanged(int, java.lang.Object) and make sure you update that item in your adapter.